# chmod - R 777 - 775 does not work what do i do?

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, chmod, upload

I'm currently developing an entertainment platform, I'm working as a web developer at a web bureau.

This project is my own personal project, it runs a LAMP stack on DigitalOcean.
At work, we have a 'third-party' guy who takes care of server setups.

I'm not very good at servers/ubuntu in general.

The problem is, I can only upload images, gifs, etc with chmod - R 777 BUT I read pretty much everywhere that this is a nono, dangerous, etc, etc.

I obviously use security in my scripts to handle files, here is my UploadFile script.

```
class UploadFile {

    protected $destination;
    protected $messages = [];
    protected $maxSize = 51200;
    protected $permittedTypes = array(
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/gif',
        'image/png',
        'image/webp'
    );
    protected $permittedHere;
    protected $name;
    protected $newName;
    protected $fixedName = false;
    protected $typeCheckingOn = true;
    protected $notTrusted = array('bin', 'cgi', 'exe', 'js', 'pl', 'php', 'py', 'sh');
    protected $suffix = '.upload';
    protected $renameDuplicates;
    protected $maxHeight;
    protected $minHeight;
    protected $maxWidth;
    protected $minWidth;
    protected $status = false;

    public function getMessages() {
        return $this->messages;
    }

    private function setMessages($type, $message) {
        $this->messages[] = [$type => $message];
    }

    public function __construct($uploadFolder, $maxHeight, $permitted = false) {
        $this->permittedHere = $permitted;
        $this->maxHeight = $maxHeight;
        if (!is_dir($uploadFolder) || !is_writable($uploadFolder)) {
            self::setMessages("error", "$uploadFolder must be a valid, writable folder.");
        }
        if ($uploadFolder[strlen($uploadFolder) - 1] != '/') {
            $uploadFolder .= '/';
        }
        $this->destination = $uploadFolder;

    }

    public function setMaxSize($bytes) {
        $serverMax = self::convertToBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
        if (is_numeric($bytes) && $bytes > 0) {
            $this->maxSize = $bytes;
        }
    }

    public function setMaxHeight() {
        $this->maxHeight = $maxHeight;
    }

    public function setMinHeight() {
        $this->minHeight = $minHeight;
    }

    public function setMaxWidth($maxWidth) {
        $this->maxWidth = $maxWidth;
    }

    public function setMinWidth($minWidth) {
        $this->minWidth = $minWidth;
    }

    public static function convertToBytes($val) {
        $val = trim($val);
        $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val) - 1]);
        if (in_array($last, array('g', 'm', 'k'))) {
            switch ($last) {
                case 'g':
                    $val *= 1024;
                case 'm':
                    $val *= 1024;
                case 'k':
                    $val *= 1024;
            }
        }
        return $val;
    }

    public static function convertFromBytes($bytes) {
        $bytes /= 1024;
        if ($bytes > 1024) {
            return number_format($bytes / 1024, 1) . ' MB';
        } else {
            return number_format($bytes, 1) . ' KB';
        }
    }

    public function allowAllTypes($suffix = null) {
        $this->typeCheckingOn = false;
        if (!is_null($suffix)) {
            if (strpos($suffix, '.') === 0 || $suffix == '') {
                $this->suffix = $suffix;
            } else {
                $this->suffix = ".$suffix";
            }
        }
    }

    public function upload($renameDuplicates = true, $fixedName = false) {
        $this->renameDuplicates = $renameDuplicates;
        $this->fixedName = $fixedName;

        $uploaded = current($_FILES);
        $this->name = $uploaded['name'];
        if (is_array($uploaded['name'])) {
            foreach ($uploaded['name'] as $key => $value) {
                $currentFile['name'] = $uploaded['name'][$key];
                $currentFile['type'] = $uploaded['type'][$key];
                $currentFile['tmp_name'] = $uploaded['tmp_name'][$key];
                $currentFile['error'] = $uploaded['error'][$key];
                $currentFile['size'] = $uploaded['size'][$key];

                if ($this->checkFile($currentFile)) {
                    $this->moveFile($currentFile);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->checkFile($uploaded)) {
                $this->moveFile($uploaded);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getNewName() {
        return $this->newName;
    }

    public function getStatus() {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function getSourceName() {
        return $this->sourceName;
    }

    protected function checkFile($file) {
//        echo "<p class='checkme'>";
//        echo "<pre>";
//        print_r($file);
//        echo "</pre>";

        if ($file['error'] != 0) {
            $this->getErrorMessage($file);
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->checkSize($file)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!empty($this->maxHeight)) {
            if (!$this->checkHeight($file)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if ($this->typeCheckingOn) {
            if (!$this->checkType($file)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        $this->checkName($file);
        return true;
    }

    protected function getErrorMessage($file) {
        switch ($file['error']) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
                self::setMessages("error", $file['name'] . " is too big: (max: " . self::convertFromBytes($this->maxSize) . ")");
                break;
            case 3:
                self::setMessages("error", $file['name'] . " was only partially uploaded.");
                break;
            case 4:
                self::setMessages("error", "No file submitted.");
                break;
            default:
                self::setMessages("error", "Sorry, there was a problem uploading " . $file['name']);
                break;
        }
    }

    protected function checkSize($file) {
        if ($file['size'] == 0) {
            self::setMessages("error", $file['name'] . " is empty.");
            return false;
        } elseif ($file['size'] > $this->maxSize) {
            self::setMessages("error", $file['name'] . " exceeds the maximum size for a file (" . self::convertFromBytes($this->maxSize) . ").");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected function checkHeight($file) {
        $data = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
        $height = $data[1];
        if ($height > $this->maxHeight) {
            self::setMessages("error", "Height exceed the limit of " . $this->maxHeight);
            return false;
        }
        if ($height > $this->minHeight) {
            self::setMessages("error", "The image should be minimum " . $this->minHeight);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function checkType($file) {
        if (in_array($file['type'], $this->permittedTypes)) {
            if (isset($this->permittedHere) && !empty($this->permittedHere)) {
                if (in_array($file['type'], $this->permittedHere)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    self::setMessages("error", $file['name'] . " is not permitted type of file.");
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            self::setMessages("error", $file['name'] . " is not permitted type of file.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected function checkName($file) {
        $this->newName = null;

            $nospaces = str_replace(' ', '_', $file['name']);
            if ($nospaces != $file['name']) {
                $this->newName = $nospaces;
            }
            $nameparts = pathinfo($nospaces);
            $extension = isset($nameparts['extension']) ? $nameparts['extension'] : '';
            if (!$this->typeCheckingOn && !empty($this->suffix)) {
                if (in_array($extension, $this->notTrusted) || empty($extension)) {
                    $this->newName = $nospaces . $this->suffix;
                } else {
                    self::setMessages("error", "Something went wrong please try again.");
                }
            }

            if ($this->fixedName){
                if (!in_array($extension, $this->notTrusted) || !empty($extension)) {
                    $this->newName = $this->fixedName . ".$extension";
                } else {
                    self::setMessages("error", "Something went wrong please try again.");
                }
            }

            if ($this->renameDuplicates) {
                $name = isset($this->newName) ? $this->newName : $file['name'];
                $existing = scandir($this->destination);
                if (in_array($name, $existing)) {
                    $i = 1;
                    do {
                        $this->newName = $nameparts['filename'] . '_' . $i++;
                        if (!empty($extension)) {
                            $this->newName .= ".$extension";
                        }
                        if (in_array($extension, $this->notTrusted)) {
                            $this->newName .= $this->suffix;
                        }
                    } while (in_array($this->newName, $existing));
                }
            }

    }

    protected function moveFile($file) {
        $filename = isset($this->newName) ? $this->newName : $file['name'];
        $success = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $this->destination . $filename);
        if ($success) {
            $result = $file['name'] . ' was uploaded successfully';
            if (!is_null($this->newName)) {
                $result .= ', and was renamed ' . $this->newName;
            }
            $result .= '.';
            self::setMessages("success", $result);
            $this->status = true;
        } else {
            self::setMessages("error", $result);
        }
    }

}
```

So if chmod - R 775 does not work for me, what other options do I have than to use chmod - R 777 ? I'm a bit confused as to how to solve this problem with folders that users can upload to?

How do I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, I can only upload images, gifs, etc with chmod - R 777 BUT I read pretty much everywhere that this is a nono, dangerous, etc, etc.

- indeed it is a big "nono". You do not want outsiders to be able to find and execute your scripts. Or be able to view configuration files where they can find passwords to databases.
- Never set anything to executable ("7") that does not need to be executable. Files that are normal at maximum need 664 but 640 is better. Directories need at maximum 775 but 770 is better ("0" means "others" can do nothing).
- It is best to have all executables outside of the webserver and indirectly start them from the webserver. That way nobody can abuse them and at most they can start them indirectly so would not receive any replies from those scripts.

If you stick to that you can use the "group" option to add both user to the same group. That makes it possible for you and others to use the group permissions (and those will be the same for all users involved).

Commands that might be of use:

- create a group "webserver": `sudo groupadd webserver`
- add user rinzwind to this group: `sudo usermod -a -G webserver rinzwind`
- list groups a user belongs to for current user `groups`

---

There is another method with a lot less to do (but also not the best method): you can have a cron job (/etc/cronjob) take care of your problem. Upload what you need to a directory structure in (for instance) your /home and set up a cronjob to do the move that places them to the correct place. /etc/cronjob can be set up to use a specific user name (and you would make that the user that owns the webserver). Solves your problem too.

Comment: This is confusing me quite a bit.

If i create a user 'rinzwind' what will this do, im a it confused.

Could you explain this to me? 'list groups a user belongs to for current user groups'

Also thanks a lot for taking the time to help me.

Comment: I never said to create a user. I simply used my name as an example on how to add rinzwind to a group.

Comment: I do however not understand the connection between creating a group and adding a user to that group. How does this connect with what's going on at the upload script? if a person creates a user on my website (stored in db etc etc) how does this relate to the group? does the server know that the website is a group, or whats going on?

When a user is logged in an try to upload anything to the server it won't because the user does not have the correct permission to do so? but when a user is logged in, what is he? he is not the owner obviously, but how is he in the 'group' that we create ?

Comment: You must *put* each person into the group. That's the second bullet: "add user rinzwind to this group"

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 every user also has a group. so your website uploader person is using a user name and group set by the webserver. That is the one you want the directories and files already present to be set to. Then you have your own user that you add to that group allowing your user to overwrite and add files.

Comment: I think I'm getting there, currently watching a great video by '
Eli the Computer Guy' on Youtube. I am however still a bit unaware of how to perform the tasks. How do I know/set where the 'directories and files already present to be set to', do I somehow have to add a group to a specific web address or how do these things work:)?